# PS3 wont boot to Safe Mode, runs for 5 seconds and powers off.

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

My PS3 won't turn on. I attempt to start it up in Safe Mode but it wont stay "on" long enough to boot.

The unit emits two beeps and then turns off. What alternative methods can I use to boot to Safe Mode?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like you're actually doing the correct procedure to get to Safe Mode, which is why you aren't getting there.

From Sony's website regarding the PS3. Emphasis is mine.

> > Activating Safe Mode
>
> Step 1: Turn off the PlayStation 3 by holding the Power button on the
>   front of the unit till the **Power light is red**.
>
> Step 2:
>
> **Touch and hold the Power button (do not remove your finger from the button). You will hear the first beep, meaning the PlayStation 3 is
>   powering on. Continue to hold the Power button and after about 5
>   seconds, you will hear a second beep, indicating the video reset.
>   Continue to hold the Power button and after about another 5 seconds
>   you will hear a third beep and the system will power off (Power light
>   is red).**
>
> Step 3:
>
> **Touch and hold the Power button (again, do not remove your finger from the button). As in Step 2, you will hear the first beep, again
>   for the PlayStation 3 to power on. Continue to hold the Power button
>   and after about 5 seconds, you will hear a second beep for video
>   reset. Continue to hold the Power button and after about another 5
>   seconds you will hear a quick double beep.** At that point release the
>   Power button. If you succeeded in activating Safe Mode, you will see a
>   message on the screen saying, "Connect the controller using a USB
>   cable and then press the PS button." Connect a USB cable to the
>   controller and the PlayStation 3 and press the PS button to enter Safe
>   Mode. You will now see the Safe Mode menu.
>
> Step 4: **We recommend performing the safe mode options in the
>   following order until one of the options works for you. If one of the
>   options work, do not continue onto the other options.**
>
> Restore Default Settings (item 2) Restore File System (item 3) Rebuild
>   Database (item 4) Restore PS3 System (item 5)